# Remove brackets in NodeJS String

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a variable in Nodejs with square baskets. I need to remove the square brackets and extract the data out of it

```
let value = "[dfsdf][dsfsd][sdfs]MY VALUE";
```

I need MY VALUE from the value variable. the number of square brackets is not final. Sometimes it will be 1 or it can go up to 4

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution without regex will be

```
value.split(']').slice(-1)[0]
```

or as per @Jeremy's comment.

```
.split("]").pop()
```

Comment: Or just `.split("]").pop()`

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution would be:

```
let value = "[dfsdf][dsfsd][sdfs]MY VALUE";
let myValue = value.substr(value.lastIndexOf(']')+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression to match square brackets:

```
/[\[\]]+/g
```

```js
let value = "[dfsdf][dsfsd][sdfs]MY VALUE";


console.log(value.replace(/[\[\]]+/g, ''))
```

---

Should you need to replace it with space use

```
value.replace(/[\[\]]+/g, ' ')
```

```js
let value = "[dfsdf][dsfsd][sdfs]MY VALUE";


console.log(value.replace(/[\[\]]+/g, ' '))
```